# Amazon Sagemaker Notebook instance stop execution as I logout

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

Currently I am exploring AWS sagemaker and I am facing a problem e.g. If I want to train my network on 1000s of epochs I cant stay active all the time. But as I logout my the notebook instance also stop execution. Is there any way to keep the instance active even after you logout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean logging out of AWS console or your laptop? Your training job should still be running on the notebook instance whether you have notebook open or not. Notebook instance will always be active until you manually stop it[1]. You can always access the notebook instance again by opening the notebook through console.

[1]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_StopNotebookInstance.html

Comment: I actually find that the notebook seems to be running still, but output stops, (at least the console output does)  which renders this less than ideal. I didnt check if output to files stops as well.